# Adding labels to my programming language

Tags: lua, interpreter

Actually I am writting a programming language in Lua. It was quite fun. I've wrote a bit of standard library (stack op and simple io). Then I've thought about labels. It would look like in assembly. While and for loop aren't funny in any bit so programming in that language can be quite challenging. Here are some requirements for this system:

- Label stack (or array, dictionary) must be accessible from global context.
- Jump instruction handler will be in separate file.

This is how my label-handling function look like:

```
function handleLabel(name,currentLine)
end
```

I have no idea how to implement this kind of magic. First I've thought about that:

```
LabelLineIDS = {}
Labels = {}
Labelamount = 1;


function handleLabel(name,currentLine)
    LabelLineIDS[Labelamount]=currentline
    Labels[Labelamount]=name
    Labelamount=Labelamount+1
end

-- In file "jump.lua":

local function has_value (tab, val)
    for index, value in ipairs(tab) do
        if value == val then
            return index
        end
    end

    print ("Error: Label not defined.") -- Bail out.
    os.exit(1)
end

local function _onlabel()
    local labelName = globalparams --Globalparams variable contain parameters to each function, at the moment
                                   --this will contain label name. It _can_ be nil.
    return LabelLineIDS[has_value(Labels, labelName)]
end
CurrLine = _onlabel() --Currline - current line that get's parsed.
                     --1 command per one line.
```

But I'm unsure is this well written or even work. Can you give me idea how to parse labels in my programming language (and write jump functions)? Or if my code is pretty ok at the moment, can you help me to improve it?

Comment: Parsing is one thing. _Interpreting_ labels/jumps - very very different story :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What tag to add instead of 'parsing'?

Comment: This one should be better

Comment: If you're writing the whole thing in Lua you could have a label table. Table keys would be label names and their values would be instruction table sizes (assuming you're putting all the instructions in a table while parsing). The jump instruction looks in the label table and moves the interpreter index to the stored size. I'm saying size here because the stored jump index is basically the size of the instruction table when the parser hits a label.

Hope I understood the question correctly.

Comment: I've decided to change my 'system'. Thanks anyway. Two days is quite much for implementing simple p/l.

Comment: How labels are implemented depend on your language, but I guess that your attempting to make labels dependent on line numbers. Also make sure you parse the code only once (tokenize and build an abstract syntax tree), then you can construct the code meanings through its A.S.T. This is very common to be done.

Comment: I've implemented this mechanism because it was easiest to write.

Comment: You're mistaken. Execute code while parsing just makes it difficult

Comment: Also, using global fields instead of locals is slower depending on how your Lua code is executed in the machine, if it is optimized, etc.. Locals will be directly referenced when expressed in most Lua compilers/executers. I'd entirely avoid globals and unnecessary general lookups, as they aren't optimized by all Lua executers (or I believe, no Lua executer does optimize them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using line counter in my parser I've decided to implement gotos like we can see in BASIC. Thanks everyone for help.